# Action of $GL_2(\mathbb R)$ on the space of lattices

Tags: group-actions, lattices-in-lie-groups

A lattice in $\mathbb C$ is an abelian subgroup of $\mathbb C$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^2$ that generates $\mathbb  C$ over $\mathbb R$. Define on the space $M$ of lattices in $\mathbb C$ a structure of smooth manifold as follows. Define a transitive action of $GL(2,\mathbb R)$ on $M$, find a stabilizer of a certain $x \in M$ and verify that it is a closed Lie subgroup. What is the dimension of $M$.

I do not really see how the action need to be defined. Any explanation or clarification of this would be helpful.

Comment: Your title question has complex numbers it it, which makes no sense.

Comment: Is $C$ the complex numbers?

Comment: Yes @Thomas Andrews

Comment: It's not clear how this makes $M$ a manifold.

Comment: The action is the action of $GL_2(\mathbb R)$ on the additive group $\mathbb C.$ It will send any lattice to a lattice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the basis $\{1,i\}$ of $\mathbb{C}$, a lattice $\Gamma$ can be obtained as the free abelian group $\left\langle\{A_\Gamma(1),A_\Gamma(i)\} \right\rangle_{\mathbb{Z}}$ generated by the images of $1$ and $i$ through a matrix $A_\Gamma\in GL_2(\mathbb{R})$. The stabiliser of a lattice $\Gamma$ is the group $ GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. The latter group acts on $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ via the left action
$$
GL_2(\mathbb{Z})\times GL_2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow GL_2(\mathbb{R})
\qquad
(Z,A)\mapsto Z\,A.
$$
The obtained quotient $GL_2(\mathbb{R})/GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is said "set of the invariant geometric lattices" and it is the $M$ you are looking for. It is a manifold of dimension $n^2$ giving in our case $\dim(M)=4$.

Comment: Thanks!. You mean that $A_{\Gamma}$ acts on $(1,0)$ and $(0,i)$ as column vectors? Why does the stabilizer equal $GL_2(Z)$?

Comment: Yes, $A_\Gamma$ acts like that

Comment: This a consequence of the definition of lattice. Let $\{v_1,v_2\}$ be a basis of the lattice $\Gamma$. Then, every element $\gamma\in\Gamma$ can be written as $\gamma=n_1\,v_1+n_2\,v_2$ with $n_1,n_2\in\mathbb{Z}$. Now, pick up another basis $\{w_1,w_2\}$ and let us denote $n_{ij}\in\mathbb{Z}$ the coordinates of $w_i$ wrt to initial basis. This gives you a transformation matrix belonging to $_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: why is the dim of $M=GL_2(R)/GL_2(Z)=2^2$?

Comment: This is related to the fact that $GL_2(Z)$ is a discrete subgroup